# How to set up MySql Replication on more than two servers?

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm looking for some help setting up MySql Replication. I've found quite a few guides and am able to get replication working on two servers, (from what I understand, a master and a slave). But I want my replication to work in such a way that there is a cluster that I can add database servers to on the fly.

I've been looking around online to find a guide that explains how to set this up, but thus far I've not found anything helpful.

This is the guide I used to get the two server replication working: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication

If anyone can point me in the direction of a guide that could help me out, I'd be incredibly appreciative. Or if someone more knowledgeable wouldn't mind explaining to me the process that would be great too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the techniques in the post [Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40379/single-slave-multiple-master-mysql-replication).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a replication cluster, the Galera cluster library enables multi-master clustering with MySQL: http://galeracluster.com/

Galera allows database servers to join and leave the cluster virtually seamlessly, and uses a quorum setup to handle the failure of one or more active database servers. Of course, a Galera cluster is not invincible, and clustered databases have their own issues. For example, Galera's structure [won't scale writes very well](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/11/17/typical-misconceptions-on-galera-for-mysql/).

Severalnines has a good list of tips for running a Galera cluser: http://severalnines.com/blog/9-tips-going-production-galera-cluster-mysql

There are fully MySQL-compatible forks that have built-in Galera support as well, such as [MariaDB Galera](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/) or [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster). They both work as near drop-in replacements.

Another solution is to use [Oracle's MySQL Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/) itself, though the architecture is a bit more complex as MySQL Cluster partitions data across the database servers instead of simply replicating the data to every server. This also means you may have to restructure your data and/or applications, but  it allows MySQL Cluster to scale writes. See the [MySQL Cluster FAQ](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/faq.html) to determine if MySQL Cluster is suited for your workload.